# FInd the missing digit in $2^{29}$ given all nine digits differ

Tags: modular-arithmetic

The number $2^{29}$ has (in base $10$) $9$ digits, all different. Which digit is missing?
I think about using fermats theorem dosen't know how to begin

Comment: What is the remainder of $2^{29}$ modulo $9$?

Comment: That is 5 how come

Comment: And what is the sum of all digits modulo $9$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$2^{29}\equiv2^{-1}\equiv\frac{1}{2}\equiv\frac{10}{2}\equiv5\equiv \text{s} \pmod 9$ where $\text{s}$ denotes the sum of its digits.

The sum of the ten digits is $\text{S}=0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9=\frac{1}{2}\times10\times9=45\equiv0 \pmod 9$

Therefore, if $2^{29}$ contains $9$ of these and the remaing one is $n$, $2^{29}\equiv S-n\equiv-n \pmod{9}$

so $s\equiv-n\equiv5 \pmod{9}$ and the missing digit is $n=4$.

Comment: Okay can you show me more in step by step?

Comment: Where is the part you don't understand ? I used Fermat's little theorem at line $1$.

Comment: S - n ≡ -n(mod 9) ?

Comment: $S$ is the sum of all the digits from $0$ to $9$, which is $45$, so $S\equiv45\equiv0 \pmod 9$. And $0-n=-n$

Comment: Actually you used [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), not Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: Right, this was Euler's, sorry. I mix them up sometimes because they're so similar.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take this opportunity to do some exponentiation by squaring... work down the left-hand column, subtracting $1$ from odd numbers and halving even numbers. then go up the right-hand column. multiplying by the base, $2$, or squaring as appropriate.

$$
\begin{array}{c|r}
x & 2^x\\\hline
29 & 536870912 \\
28 & 268435456 \\
14 & 16384 \\
7 & 128 \\
6 & 64 \\
3 & 8 \\
2 & 4 \\
1 & 2 \\
\end{array}
$$

Of course I didn't really need to go right down to the bottom, but for the sake of completeness...

Anyhow the missing digit by this labour-intensive method (yes, I did it literally on the back of an envelope while sitting at a computer) is indeed $4$.